# laravel form select dynamic change value

Tags: forms, laravel, select

I have some select forms:

```
{!! Form::select('cl_1',array('' => 'No team') + $teams, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'cl_1']) !!}
{!! Form::select('cl_2',array('' => 'No team') + $teams, null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'cl_2']) !!}
```

How I can dynamically change value of cl_2 form when I select cl_1 value;

Answer (score 0):

add this jquery code to the end of your body tag:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        $('#cl_1').change(function(
            $('#cl_2').val( $('#cl_1').val() ); //Or any code you need goes here
        ));
    );
</script>
```

Comment: cl_2 value is changing, but in the Form there is no changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("body").on("change","#cl_1",function(){
           $('#cl_2').val('1'); // You can put any value as your requirement
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: cl_2 value is changing, but in the Form there is no changes.

Comment: What you want to change on form?

Comment: I want change cl_2 value also dynamically appears in Form. Now cl_2 value changing but I don't se it at frontend.

Comment: maybe it wil be something like  $('#cl_2').append()?

Comment: Yup you are going in write way. Do it. As long as I understand your question you want to change your cl_2 select option value. If you want to do something else then you need to code for that also.

Comment: But how can I do it? $('#cl_2').text('1') and $('#cl_2').append('1') don't working.